# Avoiding data duplication in XML parsing (PHP)

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to sort my products using XML and php.I want to display
result on page in such way that :

**A) First the code could extract XML data according to my urisegment based on field (Code) and give me the related  specific product according to the segment($id) .**

**B) Secondly,it could display all the products that belong to the same category in the same page without displaying the above mentioned product again.**

My query string looks like this:
http://myspec.com/productspec/listings/10004/EDEN%2046cmTROUGH

```
<?
 $list = groupBy(file_get_contents('XML/output.xml'), "WhatMoreProductSubRange");
 $id=urldecode($this->uri->segment(4)); // URL values for WhatMoreProductSubRange 
 $id2=urldecode($this->uri->segment(3)); // URL values for Code 

 foreach ($list[$id] as $product ) 
 {
  if ($id2==$product->Code)
   {
     $subcat=$product->WhatMoreProductSubRange;

  ?>
      <h1><?=$product->Name?> </h1>
<?
   }
   else { 
?>
      <h2><?=$product->Name?> </h2>
<? 
        }
}

?>
<?
  function groupBy($xml, $categoryName) {
   $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $category = array();
    foreach ( $xml as $row ) {
     $attr = $row->attributes();

    if (! isset($attr->$categoryName)) {
        trigger_error("$categoryName does not exist in XML");
        break;
    }

    $category[(string) $attr->$categoryName][] = $attr;
  }
  return $category;
}
?>
```

**XML : output.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Rows>
<Row Code="1002" Name="EDEN TROUGH  Terracotta Blue" WhatMoreProductRange="Eden"    
WhatMoreProductSubRange="EDEN 46cmTROUGH" WhatMoreWebCategory="Garden Products" />
<Row Code="1003" Name="EDEN TROUGH  Terracotta Black" WhatMoreProductRange="Eden"    
WhatMoreProductSubRange="EDEN 46cmTROUGH" WhatMoreWebCategory="Garden Products" />
<Row Code="1004" Name="EDEN TROUGH  Terracotta Orange" WhatMoreProductRange="Eden"    
WhatMoreProductSubRange="EDEN 46cmTROUGH" WhatMoreWebCategory="Garden Products" />
<Row Code="1005" Name="EDEN TROUGH  Terracotta blue" WhatMoreProductRange="Eden"    
WhatMoreProductSubRange="EDEN 46cmTROUGH" WhatMoreWebCategory="Garden Products" />
</Rows>
```

This code outputs all the products that belong to that WhatMoreProductSubRange but i dont want repetition of product(mentioned in part A) in my product list(Mentioned in part B).I am not getting a clue how can i avoid duplication as i am new to xml parsing.Kindly help  me.

Comment: well it looks like the code attribute is unique, so just test for it and skip that row?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with XML parsing. Just create an array keyed off the products you've already output. When processing a row, check whether it's already in the array; if it's not in the array, process the row and add the product name to the array, otherwise skip the row.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your response.I tried in_array() function as you mentioned but couldn't succeed.I would appreciate if you could explain  little bit more as i am new to PHP coding.

Comment: I gave a general answer because I can't really figure out what your program is doing and I don't understand the question well. Can you show what you would like the result to look like?

Comment: @Barmar On my web page,First i want to show the product details with the "Code" retrieved in urisegment(3)i.e 1004,then i want to show all product that belong to same WhatMoreProductSubRange (An xml field for product subrange compared using urisegment(4)).In short,I want to display urisegmented(3) product,then related products based on same WhatMoreProductSubRange below as you see on many Ecommerce websites.My code is duplicating the result and showing the product again in related product list.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by "related products". It's not clear what you want to show and what you want to leave out. Please show an example of what you want the output to look like from your sample input.

Comment: @Barmar Featured Product:                                                                                                                                                                       Name :  EDEN TROUGH  Terracotta Blue                                        Subcategory : EDEN 46cmTROUGH                                            Our Other Products of this subcategory(i.e WhatMoreProductSubRange):                                               Name :  EDEN TROUGH  Terracotta Black                                        Subcategory : EDEN 46cmTROUGH    ....... and so on

Comment: I have fixed this issue.Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Sorted.Though less efficient but this one works fine.

```
<?
$list = groupBy(file_get_contents('XML/output.xml'), "WhatMoreProductSubRange");
$id=urldecode($this->uri->segment(4));
$id2=$this->uri->segment(3);
foreach ($list[$id] as $product) 
{
if ($id2==$product->Code)
{
$subcat=$product->WhatMoreProductSubRange;
 ?>
 <h1><?=$product->Name?></h1>
 <?
}
}     
?>
<?
 $list = groupBy(file_get_contents('XML/output.xml'), "WhatMoreProductSubRange");
 $id=urldecode($this->uri->segment(4));
 $id2=$this->uri->segment(3);
 foreach ($list[$id] as $product ) 
 {
   if ($id2!=$product->Code)
   {
    $subcat2=$product->WhatMoreProductSubRange;
 ?>
      <h2><?=$product->Name?></h2>
 <?
   }
  } 
  ?>
```